# Rails - Omniauth-facebook App_id required error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, omniauth, facebook-authentication, omniauth-facebook

I am interested in learning the omniauth authentication with rails so I checked different guides in which also contains Railscast #360.

When I create my own app with developers.facebook.com, it creates an App_id and secret for me. I set the application online and created a basic rails app that just uses the steps in the Ryan Bates guide.

This is my omniauth.rb file which generates the error that I am recieving,

```
 OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['875829959136178'], ENV['<app_secret>']
end
```

I have tried to use

```
provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_875829959136178'], ENV['FACEBOOK_<app_secret>']
```

also.

When I call http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook, I am recieving an error that indicates that "the parameter app_id is required".

How I can pass this error,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems you misunderstand what ENV is. `ENV[xxx]` is a ruby method which retrieves the value for environment variable `xxx`. So  `ENV['875829959136178']` in your code snippet tries to retrieve the value for environment variable `875829959136178`. It is very likely that you have not set your app_id to the environment variable `875829959136178`, and thus `ENV['875829959136178']` returns nil. `provider` is a method which takes the app_id and app_secret, but since you are giving nil as app_id, it is claiming that the app_id is not given even though it is required.

Let's say your app_id is `875829959136178` and your app_secret is `APP_SECRET`. The easiest way to make your app work is to give them as String.

```
provider :facebook, "875829959136178", "APP_SECRET"
```

You should note, though, that putting your app id and secret in source code as plain text is not desirable from security perspective. You should lean how to set environment variables by reading articles like [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/), or use gems like [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv).

Comment: An amazing explanation :) Thanks very much.
Will lean on the env variables right noe :)